# minimization in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using matlab to minimize a sum of squares (chi-squared) function. My model has a definite integral (from zero to data values).The model has three parameters w.r.t which I need to minimize.

**I need to integrate `(1+x).^(b-a-2).* exp(-b.*x)` from zero to `z(i)`, where `a` and `b` are parameters.**

I make a function handle

> > modelfun1=@ (y,a,b,c) (978.4./c).*int( (1+x).^(b-a-2).* exp(-b.*x),0,y)

and then a sum of squares function as

```
sum1=@(a,b,c,data) sum(((data.ydata-modelfun1(data.xdata,a,b,c)).^2)./data.zdata.^2);
```

where `data.xdata` has all the `z` values, `data.ydata` are the observed values and `data.zdata` are the variances.

when I minimize this function using `fminsearch`

```
[tmin,ssmin]=fminsearch(sum1,[-0.1;0.06;70],[],data)
```

I get the following error

> Error using
>
> ```
> @(a,b,c,data)sum(((data.ydata-modelfun1(data.xdata,a,b,c)).^2)./data.zdata.^2)
> ```
>
> Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in fminsearch (line 191)
>
> ```
> fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
> ```

can someone please point out what I am doing wrong. I have tried many more things but this seems to be the most recurring error.

Here is another attempt at the problem

I am trying to minimize a chi-square function (that involves a definite integral in the model)  using nlinfit. This is my attempt:
I make the model function as follows:

```
function [ f ] = modelf( p,ul )
syms x
a=p(1);
b=p(2);
c=p(3);
f=(978.4./c).*int((1+x)^(b-a-2)*exp(-b*x),x,0,ul);
end
```

here 'ul' is the upper limit of the integral.It is substituted from a data matrix z (32X1). The dependent data is in matrix y(32X1).I make another data set having weighted y values as

```
w = 1/variance;
```

where variance are the individual errors on data points
    yw = sqrt(w).*y;

and I also make a weighted function handle as

```
modelfunw=@(p,z) (sqrt(var))'.*modelf(p,z);
```

then I call nlinfit as

```
p0=[-0.1 0.05 70]'; %the initial guess

beta=nlinfit(z,yw,modelfunw,p0)
```

but I get the following error message

Error using nlinfit (line 120)
Error evaluating model function '@(p,z)(sqrt(var))'.*modelf(p,z)'.

Caused by:
    Error using mupadmex
    Error in MuPAD command: Illegal argument [checkNumber]

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong? Or is there a better way to minimize chi-square?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pack all your parameters into a single state vector.  Instead of separate parameters `a`, `b`, `c`, use `p(1)`, `p(2)`, `p(3)`.

Comment: I have tried it too and I get the following errorsError using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Illegal argument [checkNumber]

Error in sym/int (line 131)
     r = mupadmex('symobj::intdef',f.s,x.s,a.s,b.s,options);

Error in @(y,theta)(978.4./c).*int((1+x).^(theta(2)-theta(1)-2).*exp(-theta(2).*x),0,y)


Error in @(theta,data)sum(((data.ydata-modelfun1(data.xdata,theta)).^2)./data.zdata.^2)


Error in fminsearch (line 191)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

Comment: As @BenVoigt says, you have to do something like `sum1=@(p,data) ...modelfun1(data.xdata,p(1),p(2),p(3)))...;`. If this doesn't work, please post that attempt in your question and the errors you get. Your `modelfun1` can remain as is.

Comment: modelfun1=@ (y,p) (978.4./p(3)).*int( (1+x).^(p(2)-p(1)-2).* exp(-p(2).*x),0,y);
>> sum1=@(p,data) sum(((data.ydata-modelfun1(data.xdata,p)).^2)./data.zdata.^2);
>> [tmin,ssmin]=fminsearch(sum1,[-0.1;0.06;70],[],data)

Comment: error: Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Illegal argument [checkNumber]
Error in sym/int (line 131)
     r = mupadmex('symobj::intdef',f.s,x.s,a.s,b.s,options);
Error in @(y,p)(978.4./p(3)).*int((1+x).^(p(2)-p(1)-2).*exp(-p(2).*x),0,y) Error in @(p,data)sum(((data.ydata-modelfun1(data.xdata,p)).^2)./data.zdata.^2)
Error in fminsearch (line 191)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:})... I don't understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: @aymer: Try using named functions instead of anonymous function handles.  Perform each computation in multiple steps, with temporary variables, to help find out exactly what fails.  Use the MatLab debugger to find out what the values of the parameters are when the failure occurs

Comment: Thanx Ben and @mathematical.coffee for your comments. I'll try this and get back with results